# Remove duplicate element within a row in a specific column

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a dataframe such as ;

```
COL1  COL2
A,A,A 2
B     1
C,C   4
D,D,D 1
A     4
F     2
C,C   1
```

And I would like to first remove duplicate within `COL1` and get:

```
COL1  COL2
A     2
B     1
C     4
D     1
A     4
F     2
C     1
```

and then sum the same `COL1` **letter** by the `COL2` **values** and get :

```
COL1  COL2
A     6
B     1
C     5
D     1
F     2
```

Does someone have an idea, please?
Here is the dataframe if it can helps:

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"A,A,A", "B", "C,C", "D,D,D", "F"), class = "factor"), COL2 = c(2, 
1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An optoin with `trimws`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(COL1 = trimws(COL1, whitespace = ",.*")) %>% 
     summarise(COL2 = sum(COL2), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  COL1   COL2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         6
2 B         1
3 C         5
4 D         1
5 F         2
```

Answer (score 6):

A base R option

```
aggregate(
  COL2 ~ .,
  transform(
    df,
    COL1 = gsub(",.*", "", COL1)
  ),
  sum
)
```

gives

```
  COL1 COL2
1    A    6
2    B    1
3    C    5
4    D    1
5    F    2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `separate_rows` to split the data on comma in different rows, keep only unique values and aggregate.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(COL1, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  distinct(row, COL1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  summarise(COL2 = sum(COL2, na.rm = TRUE))

#  COL1   COL2
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 A         6
#2 B         1
#3 C         5
#4 D         1
#5 F         2
```

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(COL1 = gsub(",.*$", "", COL1)) %>%
 summarise(COL2 = sum(COL2))

  COL1   COL2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         6
2 B         1
3 C         5
4 D         1
5 F         2
```

If multiple non-duplicated elements could be present per rows:

```
df %>%
 group_by(COL1 = sapply(strsplit(as.character(COL1), ",", fixed = TRUE), function(x) toString(unique(x)))) %>%
 summarise(COL2 = sum(COL2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `str_extract` based on `[:alpha:]{1}`, this will `extract` the first letter in the sequence, and then continue with `group_by` and `summarise`

```
data %>% 
        mutate(COL1 = str_extract(COL1,pattern = "[:alpha:]{1}")) %>% 
        group_by(COL1) %>% 
        summarise(COL2 = sum(COL2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

It gives the following output,

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  COL1   COL2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         6
2 B         1
3 C         5
4 D         1
5 F         2
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `substring`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(COL1 = substring(COL1, 1,1)) %>% 
    group_by(COL1) %>% 
    summarise(COL2 = sum(COL2))
```

Output:

```
  COL1   COL2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         6
2 B         1
3 C         5
4 D         1
5 F         2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` as well

```
df %>% cSplit("COL1", ",", "long") %>%
  unique() %>% group_by(COL1) %>% summarise(COL2 = sum(COL2))

  COL1   COL2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         6
2 B         1
3 C         5
4 D         1
5 F         2
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `aggregate` function in `BaseR`,

```
setNames(
    aggregate(df[,2] ,list(sub(",.*","",df[,1])),sum)
    , c("COL1","COL2"))
```

gives,

```
  COL1 COL2
1    A    6
2    B    1
3    C    5
4    D    1
5    F    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
with(
  df, 
  aggregate(
    list(COL2 = COL2), 
    by = list(COL1 = gsub(
      "^(\\w).*", 
      "\\1", 
      COL1
      )
    ), 
    FUN = sum
  )
)
```